# Divide displayed data by filetype

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

```
id      time      filetype
381839  604208      ABC
414263  340248      ABC
415358  665808      DEF
428034  215805      XYZ
430640  202388      XYZ
436590  4739780     ABC
438848  635382      DEF
```

Above table is the result of my mysql query. Currently it just displays a giant table with above columns. It displays all filetypes in one column currently.

```
select * 
from  `table name` 
where id= `value`
```

Objective: I want to get different tables divided by filetypes rather than one large table mixed with all filetypes e.g.

```
Table 1:
id      time      filetype
381839  604208      ABC
414263  340248      ABC
436590  4739780     ABC

Table 2:
428034  215805      XYZ
430640  202388      XYZ

Table 3:
415358  665808      DEF
438848  635382      DEF
```

and so on.

Is there a way in sql query I can do that, or is it specific to HTML tags that the division can take place. ? I tried grouping them together by `GROUP BY` but this was not what I anticipated. Any idea in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: What you mean by `divide`? you can use `union` or just use `where filetype='ABC'`

Comment: On SQL query append: `ORDER BY filetype ASC`?

Comment: By divide I meant have separate tables for ABC, XYZ, DEF and so on filetypes. Currently all filetypes are displayed in just one table.

`where filetype = 'ABC'` will only provide me with the table comprisiong of filetypes=ABC.

Comment: @Fabiano: I already have those values in ascending order. Apologies for any confusion. The current config displays all filetypes in one giant table. I wanted to divide those tables based on filetypes.

Comment: Check my answer, you can achieve it through stored procedure unless you don't want to do it in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean this?

```
SELECT * From table ORDER BY filetype ASC
```

To group the answers with tags, you can loop the result:

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$type=$row['filetype'];
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 if($row['filetype']!=$type){
  echo 'NEW TYPE';
  $type=$row['filetype'];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting lines between groups is a client-side function.  You can use analytical functions to null out the repeating fields, if that's what you are looking for, however last time I looked, Mysql doesn't have ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ) functionality.

Also, we normally call that a 'break' in a report.

Just order by the filetype field for the query, then when it changes, change the HTML appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You said `I want to get subset of one large table divided by filetype` then just use a `WHERE` condition like

```
select * 
from  `table name` 
where filetype= 'ABC'
```

Based on your comment, you will have to do it separately like

```
create table newtbl
as
select * 
from  `table name` 
where filetype= 'ABC'
```

(OR)

Use a stored procedure like (Per latest comment, instead of creating new table go for a view)

```
create procedure newinsert (IN tabname varchar(20), IN catname varchar(10))
as
begin
    create view tabname
    as
    select * 
    from  `table name` 
    where filetype= catname
end
```

Than you can call your procedure like

```
call newinsert('newtbl','ABC') 
call newinsert('newtbl1','XYZ') 
call newinsert('newtbl2','DEF')
```

In that way, there will not be any overhead; since view doesn't store data by itself. other than this, if you are just looking for display the segregated data then I think your best bet is to get it done in your application.

Comment: Not a subset of values but tables comprising of the same filetypes in one and so on. Isnt the stored procedure creating a new table and inserting filetypes. Do you think  should be adding a table on an exisitng one and create a bit of overhead.

Comment: @learning, answer is per your post/comment. Didn't that exactly what you said in comment `By divide I meant have separate tables for ABC, XYZ, DEF and so on filetypes`. Clarify as to what you are trying to achieve cause I don't think your posted information gives much clarification then.

Comment: Yes you understood that right on. Sorry if there was any confusion. I am hesitant on adding extra tables on the existing database in order to prevent any overhead.

Comment: @learning, see edited answer for a little more clarity. You can go for creating view instead of table and that way there won't be any overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to segregate the result when you display. That cannot be done in the SQL. When you use `group by` you are just grouping the results and that is not how it will be displayed. Displaying it in distinctly marked groups needs to be done on the UI using HTML/CSS if that is what you are using.

Comment: Thats right. Exactly what I want. Currently its just a giant table with all filetypes ( in ascending order by name) but need to have separate tables for each fileset.

Comment: Now it actually depends upon how you want to display it using HTML/CSS. You can basically iterate over your result set and put each group in their own table with its own style.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comment on @rageit answer, I would

`SELECT filetype FROM table GROUP BY filetype`

So you would get all filetype available, then `foreach filetype as type`:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE filetype = type`

to get each result to handle individually.

Comment: `SELECT filetype FROM table GROUP BY filetype`
would be better as
`SELECT DISTINCT filetype FROM table`